# Excel VBA unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a text field in my userform that has the same name as a label caption without the space. For example, the textbox would be named "SampleName" and the label caption would be "Sample Name". When pressing submit, I would like the data to be entered in the workbook under the corresponding column named the same as the caption and text field name. I can't remove the space from the column header as the space is required for import into another software. However, when I hit submit it always returns a run time error unable to get match property. When I attempt this code while typing the Label.ctlname.Caption manually, it works fine. Any suggestions?

```
Dim ssheet As Worksheet
Dim rngsource As Range

Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1


With ssheet
  Set rngsource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))

Dim ctl
Dim ctlname As String

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.TextBox Then
            ctlname = "Label" & ctl.Name & ".Caption"
            .Cells(nr, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ctlname, rngsoruce, 0)) = ctl
            ctl.Text = ""
    End If
Next ctl

End With
```

Comment: Show this `Set rngsource = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))` be qualified??

Comment: So what do you want from us? how to add the space?  Why your match fails? how to properly make the string?  it appears you are missing a `.` at the end of `"Label"`.

Comment: `.Cells(nr, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ctlname, rngsoruce, 0)) = ctl` - `rngsoruce`? put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module so you can find these spelling errors easily.

Comment: To add a similar statement that  @Gary'sStudent made, `nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` may have to be qualified as well unless ssheet is the activesheet.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am particularly looking at why my match fails. To clarify further, the label is named the same as the textbox with "label" in front. For example, it would be "SampleName" as the textbox, "LabelSampleName" as the label, and "Sample Name" as the label caption. I figured it would be easier to retrieve the label based on that then add spaces to the textbox name. If I type the label's name manually into a match, it works fine. It's as soon as I enter the ctlname string into the match function it causes me problems

Comment: @dwirony Thank you for spotting that! I fixed that after I copied my code and forgot to change it when I posted. The match still doesn't seem to work even with that corrected

Comment: @davesexcel just tried both and neither seemed to do the trick. it works both ways if i manually type the label's name but neither way works the ctlname. I've also included a msgbox to make sure it's outputting the correct label name and it is.

Comment: Assuming the `TextBox` is named "ABCDE12345", the `Label` is named "LabelABCDE12345" and the `Label.Caption` is "ABCDE 12345", could you please tell us what would be the name of the column where you need to enter the data?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to:

1. Identify the `Labels` within the UserForm
2. Set the associated TextBox to the Label
3. Build the Field name and get the Field column
4. Post the TextBox value in the corresponding Field Column
5. Clear the text box

This procedure follows the steps defined above and provides for the possible formats of the Field name in the worksheet, use the format required and comment\delete the others.

```
Sub UserForm_PostToWsh()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rgSrc As Range
Dim oCtrl As Object, MsfTb As MSForms.TextBox
Dim sFld As String, lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lRow = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rgSrc = .Cells(1).Resize(1, .Cells(1).End(xlToRight).Column)
        For Each oCtrl In UfrNew_01.Controls

            Rem Validate Control as Label
            If TypeOf oCtrl Is MSForms.Label Then

                Rem Set Associated TextBox
                Set MsfTb = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set MsfTb = UfrNew_01.Controls(Replace(oCtrl.Name, "Label", vbNullString))
                On Error GoTo 0

                Rem Validate TexBox
                If Not MsfTb Is Nothing Then
                    sFld = oCtrl.Name & "." & oCtrl.Caption     'If Field format is LabelName.LabelCaption use this line
                    'sFld = oCtrl.Name & "." & MsfTb.Name        'If Field format is LabelName.TextBoxName use this line
                    'sFld = oCtrl.Caption & "." & oCtrl.Name     'If Field format is LabelCaption.LabelName use this line
                    'sFld = oCtrl.Caption & "." & MsfTb.Name     'If Field format is LabelCaption.TextBoxName use this line
                    'sFld = MsfTb.Name & "." & oCtrl.Name        'If Field format is TextBoxName.LabelName use this line
                    'sFld = MsfTb.Name & "." & oCtrl.Caption     'If Field format is TextBoxName.LabelCaption use this line

                    Rem Post Text Value
                    .Cells(lRow, WorksheetFunction.Match(sFld, rgSrc, 0)) = MsfTb.Value

                    Rem Initialize TextBox
                    MsfTb.Text = vbNullString

    End If: End If: Next: End With

    End Sub
```